# value field is not receiving php variable

Tags: php

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = '';
        $dbname = "db_code";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT Otp FROM otptable";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Otp: " . $row["Otp"] ."<br>";
                x = " . $row["Otp"] .";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <body>
         <div id="floating-panel">
              <input id="latlng" type="text" value="<?php echo $row["otp"]?>">
        </body>
```

data is not coming in value field but working in above echo.
How to insert in value??
Can i store that $row["otp"] in a variable and then echo it in value tag. if yes then how?

Comment: associative keys are case-sensitive, so `$row["otp"]` is not the same as `$row["Otp"]`

Comment: It's called after the loop has finished, so `$row` is set to false by that point. What are you expecting it to contain?

Comment: You need to add INPUT BOX CODE INSIDE loop

Comment: exactly...that variable is not working in html tag anywhere... how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to use it *outside* the loop, so `$row` doesn't contain anything meanignful by that point.  (By definition `$row` has to be `false` by then or the loop would never have ended.)

You could store the value in a variable to use after the loop, for example:

```
$otp = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $otp = $row["Otp"];
    }
}
<input id="latlng" type="text" value="<?php echo $otp; ?>">
```

Of course, be aware that **this will always display the *last* value from the loop**.  (The loop itself is kind of unnecessary at that point, you could just narrow the query to return only that one last row that you want.)  Again, this is because this is happening *outside* the loop and therefore only happens *once*, *after* the loop.

Conversely, if you want to display *multiple* values in *multiple* elements on the page, you'd more likely want to put those elements *in* the loop.  For example:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <input id="latlng" type="text" value="<?php echo $row["Otp"]; ?>">
<?php
}
```